# SOAP XML Problem with C# giving null value

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I am trying to get xml nodes with C# but I cannot make it work and variables gives me null values.

This is my soap xml:

```
            string xmlString = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:ser=""http://servicio.wstomaservicioscodimp.guatex.com/"">
                   <soapenv:Header/>
                   <soapenv:Body>
                      <ser:tomaServicioGTX>
                         <!--Optional:-->
                         <xmlentrada>
                          <![CDATA[
                            <TOMA_SERVICIO>
                                <USUARIO>WSGUATEX</USUARIO>
                                <PASSWORD>GTXWSQ23</PASSWORD>
                                <CODIGO_COBRO>CON0055</CODIGO_COBRO>
                                <SERVICIO>
                                    <TIPO_USUARIO>value</TIPO_USUARIO>
                                    <NOMBRE_REMITENTE></NOMBRE_REMITENTE>
                                    <TELEFONO_REMITENTE></TELEFONO_REMITENTE>
                                    <DIRECCION_REMITENTE></DIRECCION_REMITENTE>
                                    <MUNICIPIO_ORIGEN>A</MUNICIPIO_ORIGEN>
                                    <PUNTO_ORIGEN>A</PUNTO_ORIGEN>
                                    <ESTA_LISTO>S</ESTA_LISTO>
                                    <CODORIGEN>223</CODORIGEN>
                                    <GUIA>
                                        <LLAVE_CLIENTE></LLAVE_CLIENTE>
                                        <CODIGO_COBRO_GUIA></CODIGO_COBRO_GUIA>
                                        <NOMBRE_DESTINATARIO></NOMBRE_DESTINATARIO>
                                        <TELEFONO_DESTINATARIO></TELEFONO_DESTINATARIO>
                                        <DIRECCION_DESTINATARIO></DIRECCION_DESTINATARIO>
                                        <MUNICIPIO_DESTINO></MUNICIPIO_DESTINO>
                                        <PUNTO_DESTINO></PUNTO_DESTINO>
                                        <RECOGE_OFICINA></RECOGE_OFICINA>
                                        <CODDESTINO></CODDESTINO>
                                    </GUIA>
                                </SERVICIO>
                            </TOMA_SERVICIO>
                          ]]>
                         </xmlentrada>
                      </ser:tomaServicioGTX>
                   </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

I am just trying to get **TIPO_USUARIO**, **NOMBRE_REMITENTE**, **TELEFONO_REMITENTE** and so on.. Nodes and fill them with information.

I have tried this:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlString);

        // Select the "TIPO_USUARIO" node using XPath
        XmlNode tipoUsuarioNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//SERVICIO/TIPO_USUARIO");

        // Get the value of the "TIPO_USUARIO" node
        string tipoUsuarioValue = tipoUsuarioNode.InnerText;
```

but the problem is *tipoUsuarioNode* is giving me null and I cannot figure it out why. How can I solve this? I am trying this for hours many forms and nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML that you want to edit is doubly wrapped into a `CDATA` element. You need to parse out the outer XML, get the CDATA element and parse that, then you can edit it and write it back.

Linq-To-XML is much better for this kind of thing

```cs
var xml1 = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
var data = (XCData) xml1.Descendants("xmlentrada").First().Nodes().First();
var xml2 = XElement.Parse(data.Value);
var SERVICIO = xml2.Element("SERVICIO");
SERVICIO.Element("TIPO_USUARIO").Value = "someName";
// more changes here
data.Value = SERVICIO.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(xml1);
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pef1HL)

Comment: And how could I get nodes inside <GUIA>?

Comment: `SERVICIO.Element("GUIA").Elements()` You would make those changes at the point I marked `// more changes here` and then write the changes back using `data.Value = SERVICIO.ToString();`

Answer (score 1):

Check it out how to do it via `LINQ to XML` API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

The term CDATA means, Character Data. CDATA section is defined as blocks of text that are not parsed by the parser, but are otherwise recognized as markup.

That's why solution has three steps:

1. Get CData section as text into `XDocument xmlentrada`.
2. Get SERVICIO element out of it.
3. Get individual XML elements of interest textual values.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ser='http://servicio.wstomaservicioscodimp.guatex.com/'>
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <ser:tomaServicioGTX>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <xmlentrada><![CDATA[
                                <TOMA_SERVICIO>
                                    <USUARIO>WSGUATEX</USUARIO>
                                    <PASSWORD>GTXWSQ23</PASSWORD>
                                    <CODIGO_COBRO>CON0055</CODIGO_COBRO>
                                    <SERVICIO>
                                        <TIPO_USUARIO>value</TIPO_USUARIO>
                                        <NOMBRE_REMITENTE>value2</NOMBRE_REMITENTE>
                                        <TELEFONO_REMITENTE></TELEFONO_REMITENTE>
                                        <DIRECCION_REMITENTE></DIRECCION_REMITENTE>
                                        <MUNICIPIO_ORIGEN>A</MUNICIPIO_ORIGEN>
                                        <PUNTO_ORIGEN>A</PUNTO_ORIGEN>
                                        <ESTA_LISTO>S</ESTA_LISTO>
                                        <CODORIGEN>223</CODORIGEN>
                                        <GUIA>
                                            <LLAVE_CLIENTE></LLAVE_CLIENTE>
                                            <CODIGO_COBRO_GUIA></CODIGO_COBRO_GUIA>
                                            <NOMBRE_DESTINATARIO></NOMBRE_DESTINATARIO>
                                            <TELEFONO_DESTINATARIO></TELEFONO_DESTINATARIO>
                                            <DIRECCION_DESTINATARIO></DIRECCION_DESTINATARIO>
                                            <MUNICIPIO_DESTINO></MUNICIPIO_DESTINO>
                                            <PUNTO_DESTINO></PUNTO_DESTINO>
                                            <RECOGE_OFICINA></RECOGE_OFICINA>
                                            <CODDESTINO></CODDESTINO>
                                        </GUIA>
                                    </SERVICIO>
                                </TOMA_SERVICIO>
                              ]]>
                </xmlentrada>
            </ser:tomaServicioGTX>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>");
    
    XDocument xmlentrada = XDocument.Parse(xdoc.Descendants("xmlentrada").FirstOrDefault().Value);

    XElement servicio = xmlentrada.Descendants("SERVICIO").FirstOrDefault();
    
    Console.WriteLine("TIPO_USUARIO='{0}', NOMBRE_REMITENTE='{1}'",
      servicio.Element("TIPO_USUARIO")?.Value,
      servicio.Element("NOMBRE_REMITENTE")?.Value);
}
```

**Output**

```
TIPO_USUARIO='value', NOMBRE_REMITENTE='value2'
```